# What is the use case of GIC interrupt bypass

Tags: arm

I am not able to relate to the use case of GIC interrupt bypass in linux.
Is there a acutal usecase for it?

Comment: Another use (depending on what you are talking about) is that the nIRQ line may drive to a core directly.  The **GIC** is a multi-core controller with a *distributor*.  With *bypass*, the distributor is not used and the CPU with the nIRQ services the peripheral.

Comment: @artlessnoise From ARM cortex-a9 documentation - PPI[0]"In legacy FIQ mode the legacy nFIQ pin, on a per Cortex-A9 processor basis, bypasses the interrupt distributor logic and directly drives interrupt requests into the Cortex-A9 processor. When a Cortex-A9 processor uses the Interrupt Controller, rather than the legacy pin in the legacy mode, by enabling its own Cortex-A9 processor interface, the legacy nFIQ pin is treated like other interrupt lines and uses ID28" - So it seems like it uses PPI[0] to route the legacy interrupt.

Comment: @artlessnoise I think i figured it out. The GIC is bypassed in the Legacy mode and the interrupt is sent to the CPU interface directly ( by passing the Distributor logic). This can be set as one of the configurations in the GIC ( can be done by setting some bits in the ICCICR register). It is called the legacy mode. More information can be found in http://www.systems.ethz.ch/sites/default/files/file/aos2012/ReferenceMaterial/InterruptHandling/GIC_architecture_spec_v1_0.pdf

Comment: mSO, See Nuetrino's question [What are legacy interrupt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238921/what-are-legacy-interrupts); it is related.  Probably you have already solved your issue and moved on...